# Hotspot on Kubuntu (Ubuntu 13.10)

Tags: wireless, kubuntu, 13.10

Before I begin, I should say don't mention Ad-Hoc. Ad-Hoc is not a "Hotspot", as most Android devices don't support Ad-Hoc connections (I've tested many devices). For example, I know of Connectify for Windows but it isn't available for Linux and it doesn't run with WINE. I have an Ethernet-connected laptop and want to share its network wirelessly to use on my Galaxy S3.

Answer (score 4):

Copy paste to a similar question I just answered. I use this method exactly for the same reason you said, since it's the only way I can connect my Android phone to the net:

I use this script described in this post to create a hotspot in my Ubuntu server:

http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/how-to-set-up-wireless-hotspot-access.html

Basically, it helps you create a hotspot. You'll need to have two interfaces in the computer you want to use, one connected to the internet, and the serving the hotspot.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ap-hotspot
```

When it's installed, run:

sudo ap-hotspot configure

It will ask you a few questions (internet interface, wireless interface to create the access point, password) and then the hotspot can be run and stopped with:

```
sudo ap-hotspot start
sudo ap-hotspot stop
```

Note than this script automates the process of creating the hotspot, which can be done manually installing and configuring dns-masq and hostapd, but the result is the same.

Comment: Thank you very much, I've been looking for something that worked with Android for forever!